# OnPlaceSelectedListener of SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment not fired

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, google-maps-android-api-2, google-places-api

I'm having a problem with the **OnPlaceSelectedListener** method of a **SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment**.

My **onViewCreated()** method:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    // Initialise a new fragment inside of this one.
    mFragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
    mSupportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("mapFragment");
    mSupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment = (SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment) mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("autocompleteFragment");

    // Never inflate fragments inside other fragments in a layout.xml!
    // Do it programmatically.
    // See here for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19815266/4938112.
    if (mSupportMapFragment == null) {
        mSupportMapFragment = new SupportMapFragment();
        fragmentTransaction(mFragmentManager, mSupportMapFragment, R.id.map_fragment_container, "mapFragment");
    }

    // Asynchronous thread to load map.
    mSupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


    if (mSupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment == null) {
        mSupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment = new SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment();
        fragmentTransaction(mFragmentManager, mSupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment, R.id.card_view, "autocompleteFragment");
    }

    // Filter for a specific place type.
    AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
            .setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_CITIES)
            .build();
    mSupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment.setFilter(typeFilter);

    Log.d("I'M HERE", "Hello.");

    mSupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
            // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
            Log.i("PLACE", "Place: " + place.getName());
            int flag = 1;
            Log.d("FLAG", "flag: " + flag);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
            Log.i("PLACE_ERROR", "An error occurred: " + status);
            int flag = 0;
            Log.d("FLAG", "flag: " + flag);
        }
    });

    Log.d("I'M HERE, TOO", "Hello.");

}
```

When I select a place (all the APIs are enabled and I've a Google Key), the AutoCompleteFragment just closed and nothing happens on the map.
The **mSupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(...)** method is not being fired.

Any hints?

My problem is similar to the one in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34507708/onplaceselectedlistener-of-supportplaceautocompletefragment-not-fired-inside-vie).

I'm using nested fragments, too and I can't understand how to see the **onActivityResult()** method in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved this problem: hope it will help someone.

I added this infamous line in the **onActivityResult()** method in my MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    ...
}
```

and then did put the same method in my MapFragment

```
    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Now the nested fragment is sending back its data.