# Place Autocomplete closes immediately

Tags: android, autocomplete, google-places-api

I am having a problem using the Google Places Autocomplete SDK, I already found some answers, however, that didn't resolve the problen. In particular, related questions and answers were found [here](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete#troubleshooting/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38180608/onplaceselectedlistener-of-supportplaceautocompletefragment-not-fired). The documentation on the Android developers site is [here](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete#troubleshooting).

I activated the Places SDK for Android (and the Maps SDK for Android) and pasted the created API Key into my strings.xml file. The map is working just fine, however the autocomplete widget is closing immediately after selecting it and in the logcat I get the error:

```
05-23 06:00:40.376 14951-14951/com.example.tobi.beparty I/LOCATIONACTIVITY: An error occurred: Status{statusCode=ERROR, resolution=null}
```

Due to the linked answers, I was thinking that something is wrong with the API keys, however, in the Google APIs dashboard, I see every request (with an error rate of 100%), therefore I think this is not the problem. Moreover, I tried to implement the Place Autocomplete version with an intent (as described in the documentation) but faced the same problem which is why I think, the fragment is also not the problem.

Any suggestions? Many thanks in advance!

Manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.example.tobi.beparty">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

<application
    android:name=".ParseApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key"/>

    <activity android:name=".LogInActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".LocationActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_location">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SearchActivity"/>
</application>
```

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.tobi.beparty.LocationActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/relLayoutBotBar">

    <fragment
      xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/map"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/white_border"
        android:id="@+id/relLayout1">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/ic_magnify"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_magnify"/>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ic_magnify"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:background="@null"
            android:hint="Enter the party name"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/relLayoutBotBar"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/white_grey_border_top"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu">
    </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Java:

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceSelectionListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class LocationActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

final private String TAG = "LOCATIONACTIVITY";

private GoogleMap mMap;

LocationManager locationManager;
LocationListener locationListener;

EditText mSearchText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.location_layout);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
     SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    // mSearchText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);


    PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);

    autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
            // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
            Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
            Log.i(TAG, "An error occurred: " + status);
        }
    });


    /* Bottom Navigationbar*/
    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottomBar);
    BottomNavigationViewHelper.disableShiftMode(bottomNavigationView);
    Menu menu = bottomNavigationView.getMenu();
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.getItem(3);
    menuItem.setChecked(true);
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.ic_search:
                    Intent intentSearch = new Intent(LocationActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intentSearch);
                    break;

                case R.id.ic_favorite:
                    Intent intentFavorite = new Intent(LocationActivity.this, FavoriteActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intentFavorite);
                    break;

                case R.id.ic_cake:
                    Intent intentParties = new Intent(LocationActivity.this, PartiesActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intentParties);
                    break;

                case R.id.ic_location:
                    Intent intentLocation = new Intent(LocationActivity.this, LocationActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intentLocation);
                    break;

                case R.id.ic_person:
                    Intent intentProfile = new Intent(LocationActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intentProfile);
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    /* LatLng center = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    String centerName = "Sydney"; */

    LatLng center = new LatLng(13.307, 52.500068);
    String centerName = "Adenauerplatz";


    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(center).title("Marker in " + centerName));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(center, 10));

    locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Log.i(TAG, location.toString());
            Toast.makeText(LocationActivity.this, location.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // LatLng center = new LatLng(-34, 151);
            LatLng center = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            String centerName = "current position";
            mMap.clear();
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(center).title("Marker in " + centerName));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(center, 10));

            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());

            try {
                List<Address> listAddresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
                if(listAddresses != null && listAddresses.size() > 0){
                    Log.i(TAG, listAddresses.get(0).toString());
                    String address = "";
                    if(listAddresses.get(0).getSubThoroughfare() != null){
                        address += listAddresses.get(0).getSubThoroughfare() + "";
                    }
                    if(listAddresses.get(0).getThoroughfare() != null){
                        address += listAddresses.get(0).getThoroughfare() + "";
                    }
                    if(listAddresses.get(0).getLocale() != null){
                        address += listAddresses.get(0).getLocale() + ", ";
                    }
                    if(listAddresses.get(0).getPostalCode() != null){
                        address += listAddresses.get(0).getPostalCode() + ", ";
                    }
                    if(listAddresses.get(0).getCountryName() != null){
                        address += listAddresses.get(0).getCountryName() + "";
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(LocationActivity.this, address, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }
    };

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
    } else {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
        } else {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
            Location lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            String lastKnownLocationName;
            LatLng lastKnownLatLng;
            if(lastKnownLocation == null){
                lastKnownLatLng = new LatLng(52.500068, 13.307);
                lastKnownLocationName = "Adenauerplatz";
            }else{
                lastKnownLatLng = new LatLng(lastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), lastKnownLocation.getLongitude());
                lastKnownLocationName = "Last known location";
            }
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(lastKnownLatLng).title(lastKnownLocationName));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(lastKnownLatLng, 10));
        }
    }

}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener); // ToDo: Die zahlen hier stehen dafür, wieviele Meter bzw. Sekunden gegangen werden müssen, dass ein Update erfolgt. evtl. ändern

        }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: See the description here :-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31449649/android-google-places-api-getautocompletepredictions-returns-status-places-api/54567092#54567092

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue when following the [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration#install_the_compatibility_library) to use the Places compatibility library.

The problem is that Google considers the original "Places SDK for Android" and the new "Places API" two different APIs.  As a result, you need to go into the Google Cloud Platform and enabled the new "Places API".

If you haven't enabled it yet, it will appear under the "Additional APIs" section - click on it, and then click on "Enable".

After you've enabled it, the new Places API should appear under the "Enabled APIs" section as shown below:

[image]

After I did this the autocomplete window stayed open and worked correctly.